# GPU in docker container for deep learning task

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Recently, I have started working on using docker images. I want to deploy PyTorch based text classification model which requires GPU to run on. When the docker image is called upon, then it's not able to detect GPU in the VM. Hence, my code is failing by throwing `no Cuda device found error`.

This is my base image `FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-gpu.1-0`. I don't know what all steps to follow to install Nvidia drivers in the docker. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Nvidia drivers into the container doesn't help since the GPU device isn't exposed to the container. Running with [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) instead does.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Click through to the link, read the instructions, use nvidia-docker to run your image.

Comment: I have to run it in the kubernetes pod operator. Is it possible to do so with above method?

Comment: You never said that in your original post. That would have been a good thing to know. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/